# Saving txt file from TextInput and then re loading it in separate Window/Class Kivy

Tags: python, pandas, kivy, kivy-language

Trying to create a basic version of the website "leafly".
I want use user input to look up a row in a data set and display all the information on whatever the user has typed in.

I save the user's TextInput to a txt file and then open the text file in the next window.
The txt file saves fine but for some reason it will only load the right text after i've closed the app.
 So if the user inputs text into the InputText box it will save to the txt file, but when i try to display that txt file in the next window it only loads what the text file was before loading the programme.
If i run the programme again the previous user input works but i want it to work live without having to close the app.

I am new to python so that might explain any weird code you see haha.
The data set i am using can be found here: https://www.kaggle.com/kingburrito666/cannabis-strains

Also i know how funny and ridiculous this is haha but if you can help i'd appreciate it!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import pandas as pd
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from pathlib import Path

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)

df = pd.read_csv("cannabis.csv", sep=",")

class Menu(Screen):
    pass

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    st = str("")
    str(df[df['Strain'].str.match(st)])
    type = ObjectProperty(None)

    def btn(self):

        self.st = self.st + str(self.type.text)
        self.st = str(self.st)

        print(self.st, file=open("text.txt", "w"))
```

then

```
class ThirdWindow(Screen):

    with open('text.txt', 'r') as myfile:
        data = myfile.read().strip()

    strain = StringProperty(str(df[df['Strain'].str.match(str(data))]))

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__== "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

.kv file

```
WindowManager:
    Menu
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:
    ThirdWindow:

<Menu>:
    name: "menu"

    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        Button:
            text: "Launch My Weed"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
```

then

```
<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"

    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        GridLayout:
            cols:2

            Label:
                text: "Password: "

            TextInput:
                id: password
                multiline: False

        Button:
            text: "Login"
            on_release:
            app.root.current = "second" if password.text == "password" else "main"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
```

then

```
<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    type: type



    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        GridLayout:
            cols:2

            Label:
                text: "Strain?: "

            TextInput:
                id: type
                multiline: False



        Button:
            text: "Tell Me About My Weed"
            on_release:


            app.root.current = "third"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "down"
            root.btn()



<ThirdWindow>:
    name: "third"


    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        GridLayout:
            cols:2




            Label:
                text : root.strain
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read the text file in the class definition of `ThirdWindow` which happens at startup, if you want it to happen when you enter the screen, you can put this code in the `on_pre_enter` (or `on_enter` but this will happen after the transition has complete, so if it changes the content, it might "flash").

```py
class ThirdWindow(Screen):
    strain = StringProperty()

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        with open('text.txt', 'r') as myfile:
            data = myfile.read().strip()
            self.strain = str(df[df['Strain'].str.match(str(data))])
```

Comment: Wow that makes so much sense, thank you! Can always count on Tshirtman